# 14.10 apt-get unable to locate package libopenal-dev in chroot

Tags: apt, 14.10, chroot

I'm trying to develop Torque2D on a 32-bit chroot, as there's no 64-bit version as of yet, and it requires libopenal-dev, among other packages to compile properly. I've tried compiling it without it without success, and here's the problem I'm trying to surmount.

If I try

```
apt-get install libopenal-dev
```

It simply says

```
E: Unable to locate package libopenal-dev
```

if I'm in chroot, but installs fine outside. The other packages that torque2D required installed fine inside the chroot as well. Little help?

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` when you are in chroot or `cat /chroot/etc/apt/sources.list` from outside the chroot.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple fix. Just copy the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` from outside `chroot`, then log-in back to `chroot` and open up `/etc/apt/sources.list` (inside `chroot`) and paste the contents. You just need to do `sudo apt-get update` inside `chroot` and you're ready to `apt-get install libopenal-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to update your repositories.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I tried that, I'll give it another shot.